How to call the ngOnInit of one component from another component
I have 2 files that load data into 1 page. I want the content of component B to get loaded when components of component A are being loaded onto the page.
Component A.
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap(
          (params) =>
            (this.params = params?.filters ? JSON.parse(params.filters) : {})
        ),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.http
            .get(
              this.configPrv.AppSetting.uriReports
                .getReportsDashboardConfig,
              {
                withCredentials: true,
              }
            )
            .pipe(
              tap(
                
                (response: {
                  fields: FieldsDefinition<Form>;
                  dimensions?: string;
                }) => {
                  this.form = this.formGenerator.init(
                    {
                      layout: {
                        'grid-template-columns': '1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr',
                        'column-gap': '1.5em',
                      },
                      fields: response.fields,
                    },
                    this.params
                  );
                 
                }
              ),
              switchMap(() =>
                this.form.values$.pipe(
                  tap(
                    (values: Form) =>
                      (this.reportEndpoint = values?.report || '')
                  ),
                  tap((filters) =>
                    this.router.navigate(['./'], {
                      relativeTo: this.route,
                      queryParams:
                        Object.keys(filters).length !== 0
                          ? { filters: JSON.stringify(filters) }
                          : {},
                    })
                  )
                )
              )
            )
        ),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroySubject)
      )
      .subscribe();
    
  }

Component B
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get<ReportBuilderReportConfig>(
        this.configPrv.AppSetting.uriReports.getReportsDashboardConfig,
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .pipe(tap((response) => {}))
      .subscribe((resp) => {});
  }

When the page is loaded, contents of component A are loaded but I want to have contents of component B load as well.

I'm having some trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve, if an instance of Component B is located in Component A's template, then the ngOnInit function will be run.

When component A has finished loading Component B (if it's a child) will automatically get triggered.
My understanding is that you are making the API call on componentA, but you are making the same API call on component B, since it's already made in A, you want to pass the response to ComponentB.
There are two ways to do this.
You can use @Input and pass the data through HTML (create a new property and store the response from API if needed) before passing to component B:
<app-componentb [response]="response" [form]="form"/>

TS:
@Component({...}
export class ComponentB {
    @Input() response: any;
    @Input() form: any;

Another way is to use a common service, ng g c CommonService, ensure you have providedIn: 'root' in the injector object
@Injector({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {
    response: any;
    form: any;
}

Then on the parent, assign the data you need to the service
Component A
@Component({...})
export class ComponentA {
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
        ...
            (response: {
              fields: FieldsDefinition<Form>;
              dimensions?: string;
            }) => {
              this.response = this.commonService.response = response;
              this.form this.commonService.form = this.formGenerator.init(
                {
                  layout: {
                    'grid-template-columns': '1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr',
                    'column-gap': '1.5em',
                  },
                  fields: response.fields,
                },
                this.params
              );
             
            }
          ),

Component B:
@Component({...})
export class ComponentB {
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.commonService.response);
    // do something with the data!
 }
 ...


Spelling tip: the English contraction it's (meaning "it is") takes an apostrophe. Your spelling checker won't highlight this because the word its is correctly spelled for a different context (e.g. "the dog enjoys gnawing on its bone"). Here the word is used in a possessive context.

At a guess, you have around 200 posts with this error in. Since you are a prolific poster, it would be ideal if you would ensure this is correctly spelled in your new posts. It otherwise creates a lot of fix work, and we surely do not have enough volunteer editors.

@halfer sorry for the wasted time, will do better!

Thank you so much @NarenMurali, I was able to use a common service and I was able to make the contents of component B load.
